# Formatting consolidated output in sh

Tags: shell, printf, sh

I currently have an output in bash that looks like:

```
"a" "a" "b" => no
"a" "a" => yes
"b" => yes
"a" "b" "a" "b" => no
```

I'm using printf, but the problem is that to create these strings I'm looping over a bunch of results from a program and concatenating them so the formatting doesn't work how I want it to. I would love for them to be two columns- the letters and then "=> yes" or "=> no" as the second column.

Here is how I have set them up (this is all in a loop going through a bunch of results):

```
while read -r line
do
  python3 ./fsa_acceptor.py "$2" "$line" >"fsa$counter"
  chmod +x "fsa$counter"
  carmel_result=$(carmel "$1" "fsa$counter")
  if test -z "$carmel_result"
  then
    output+="$line => no"
  else
    output+="$line => yes"
  fi
  output+="\n"
  counter=$((counter+1))
done < "$filename"
  printf "$output" > result_file
```

How can I reformat this when I'm printing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use Column:

```
$ column -ts "=" result_file 
"a" "a" "b"       > no
"a" "a"           > yes
"b"               > yes
"a" "b" "a" "b"   > no
```

However, as you can see, it consumes the equal sign. If your Column has the `-o` flag, add `-o "="` to the command and you're done. If not, you can restore it with Sed:

```
$ column -ts "=" result_file | sed 's/>/=>/'
"a" "a" "b"       => no
"a" "a"           => yes
"b"               => yes
"a" "b" "a" "b"   => no
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223117/discussion-between-quasimodo-and-iamjane).